# How to query one attribute of mySQL database and compare results to a form variable?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

In my control page, I need to query my usersas6 table for all username entries and compare to $username from a form on my view page. The rest of the code is fine. I have tried this but I do not seem to add anything to the $myerror variable even when there is already an entry in the table with the form username.

```
  public function addPerson()
    {
      // GET AND SET POSTED DATA
      $username = $this->input->post('username');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');
      $accesslevel = $this->input->post('accesslevel');

      $myerror = "";
      // add the person to database with

        if (strlen($username) < 1)
        {
          $myerror = "The Username field is required.";
        }

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM usersas6");
          foreach ($query->result() as $entry)
          {
              if ($username == $entry){
                $myerror .= "The Username is taken.";
              }
          }

        if(strlen($myerror) != 0){
          $this->TPL["myError"] = $myerror;
        }
        $this->getAllPerson();
        $this->template->show('Admin', $this->TPL);
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you just use where clause and check if there is a return row instead of looping all of the records ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
$myerror = array();
// add the person to database with

if (empty($username))
{
    $myerror[] = "The Username field is required.";
}
else
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM usersas6 WHERE username = '$username' "); # search for specific Username
    $result = $query->num_rows(); # count rows 

    if (!empty($result)) # or  if ($result > 0) 
    {
        $myerror[] = "The Username is taken.";
    }   
}

$this->TPL["myError"] = $myerror;
```

> **FYI:** It's better to use **Model** do DB queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try This to check the username in database

In your model

```
public function function_name($username){
return $this->db->get_where('username', $username)->row()->username;
}
```

In your controller

```
$this->load->model('model_name')l
$query = $this->model_name->function_name($username);
if($query)
{
    //Coding...
}
```